# Using SPFile.OpenBinary() fails with "Cannot open file". StoragePoint RBS issue?

Tags: sharepoint

I'm trying to restore a file from a backup content database in SharePoint 2016 by using the Get-SPContentDatabase -ConnectAsUnattachedDatabase and drilling down to the item level to use the OpenBinary() call. I believe this is failing because the BLOB is externalized via StoragePoint, but I'm not sure how to allow this command to access the external BLOB data. Any ideas on what permissions might be necessary? The BLOB and endpoint still exist in SharePoint and on the file share and I am successfully able to see the item and its properties within PowerShell.

I found a similar issue where the OP said they solved it by giving explicit permissions to the StoragePoint databases, but Imm not sure what permissions or which databases need them. [listItem.File.OpenBinary()  not working - Remote Blob Storage / FileStreaming not enabled on SQL Server the culprit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6645272/listitem-file-openbinary-not-working-remote-blob-storage-filestreaming-no)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out. I was testing from a server that didn't have the full StoragePoint installation. Testing the same call from one of the web servers in the farm I was able to open and download the file.