# 401 unauthorized exception while reading data from the document library SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, comexception, unauthorizedaccessexcepti

We developed a WebPart to read the content of the file in the document library in the SiteCollection. I used the following code to read the content.

```
 WebClient wc = new WebClient();
 wc.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
 string documenturl = siteurl+"/" + file.Url.ToString();
 content = wc.DownloadData(documenturl);//documenturl is the file path of the document
```

But, i got the following error 401 unathorized exception

```
System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error:(401) Unauthorized. at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal(Uri address,WebRequest& request) at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadData(Uri address)
```

For your information, i already tried to download document by SPFile openBinary method. But it only works when the document is small. Please refer the below site.

[getting ComException while reading the document in SharePoint 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3924491/getting-comexception-while-reading-the-document-in-sharepoint-2010)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the [local loopback check](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896861). (Verify by trying to access your site using the same URL whilst using IE running on your SharePoint server)

Also - any reason why you're using web services to access local content rather than the SharePoint object model (Microsoft.SharePoint.dll)?

Comment: Hi Ryan, Thank you for your input. We already used the SharePoint object model. But we are getting com Exception, when file size is exceed 100kb. Please refer the below [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3924491/getting-comexception-while-reading-the-document-in-sharepoint-2010)(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3924491/getting-comexception-while-reading-the-document-in-sharepoint-2010)